# Calculating the molecular mass of an element using relative molecular mass in several compounds

Tags: physical-chemistry, stoichiometry

> The relative molecular masses of A, B, and C were found to be $101.30$, $87.30$ and $144.90$ respectively, compared to an assigned value of exactly $2.00$ for $\ce{H2}$. Subsequently, these substances were subjected to elemental analysis and were found to contain $37.2\%$, $64.8\%$ and $78.0\%$ of $\ce{X}$ respectively by mass.
>
> Find the molecular mass of element  X, found in A, B & C.

I found the relative molecular mass of X in each of the three compounds:

In A, $$101.3 \times 0.372 = 37.68$$

In B,

$$87.3 \times 0.648 = 56.57$$

In C,

$$144.9 \times 0.78 = 113.022$$

I calculated the HCF of these three values. However my answer doesn't match with the actual answer. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: It would be good to hear your final answer.

Comment: Is the answer 18.84?

Comment: The twist is that there are one or more atoms of X in compounds A, B, and C.